# I try to add informations to User profile

Tags: users

I try to add information fields to User profile. But my code doesn't run! :-(

In `functions.php` I add:

```
function add_contact_profile($user_contact) {
    $user_contact['twitter'] = __('URL Twitter');
    $user_contact['facebook'] = __('URL Facebook');
    $user_contact['googleplus'] = __('');
    $user_contact['linkedin'] = __('URL Linkedin');
    return $user_contact;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'add_contact_profile', 99);
```

and in `header.php` I add:

```
<?php
if(get_the_author_meta('rss_url') ){
    echo('<a href="'. get_author_feed_link( get_the_author_meta('ID') ) .'" target="_blank" class="social rss_url socialtooltip rss" data-original-title="RSS">
            <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
        </a>');
}
echo('<a href="'. get_the_author_meta('googleplus') .'" target="_blank" class="social googleplus socialtooltip social-google-plus" data-original-title="Google+">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
    </a>');
if(get_the_author_meta('facebook') ){
    echo('<a href="'. get_the_author_meta('facebook') .'" target="_blank" class="social facebook socialtooltip social-facebook" data-original-title="Facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>');
}
if(get_the_author_meta('twitter') ){
    echo('<a href="'. get_the_author_meta('twitter') .'" target="_blank" class="social twitter socialtooltip social-twitter" data-original-title="Twitter">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>');
}
if(get_the_author_meta('linkedin') ){
    echo('<a href="'. get_the_author_meta('linkedin') .'" target="_blank" class="social facebook socialtooltip social-linkedin" data-original-title="LinkedIn">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>');
}
?>
```

**P.S.**

With

`var_dump(get_the_author_meta('googleplus'));`

I get

`string(0);`

My theme is: Twenty Thirteen

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried your code and it works when you do like below:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // this will give user id of current loged in user 

// or try using this to get author ID related to your post, this will give $user_id of post author
$temp_post = get_post($post_id);
$user_id = $temp_post->post_author;



var_dump(get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user_id ));
```

similarly  for other fields, please replace in your code accordingly:

```
get_the_author_meta('googleplus',$user_id)

get_the_author_meta('facebook',$user_id)

get_the_author_meta('linkedin',$user_id)
```

For details Please follow [get_the_author_meta codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

For more details please follow this link [get_the_author_meta developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)

I think we need to pass `$user_id` when need to use outside the loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I need `$user_id`, I try to use: `$temp_post = get_post($post_id);
$user_id = $temp_post->post_author;` but the $user_id is blank

Comment: This will give you `$user_id` from post and that will be of post author. Or other way you can get `$user_id` of logged-in user. I think this is way how we get `$user_id`. Please explain how you want to display user relevant information.

Comment: How can I  use `$user_id` in 404 page (or search page, ecc. ecc.)?

Comment: please clear what exactly you want. I assume if information is user specific then it will be either shown when user are loged-in or on post of user. In other case I think some default information can be shown.

Comment: how do I print to video the phone number regardless of which page type am I? Whith the `get_the_author_meta`.